# join and repeat value from a column of another table

Tags: oracle, join

I have two table A and B

**Table A**

```
C1
----
11
232
454
65
78
87
45
87
98
99
```

**Table B**

```
C2
----
c1
c2
c3
c4
```

How can I join these table to get output like

```
C1, C2
--------
11  ,c1
232 ,c2
454 ,c3
65  ,c4
78  ,c1
87  ,c2
45  ,c3
87  ,c4
98  ,c1
99  ,c2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query seems to work,If anybody has better solution please comment.

```
select
    c1,c2
from
    (select mod(rownum,(select count(1) from r2))+1 rn,customer_Key as c1 from r1) t1, 
    (select rownum rn,customer_Key as c2 from r2) t2 
    where 
    t1.rn=t2.rn
```

Comment: Please explain how it works.

Comment: using the `rownum` as you suggested , I modified the rn of table A to fall in the same  range to that of the table B and then used to them join.

Answer (score 1):

Since the tables have no column in common, we'll have to use the `rownum` pseudocolumn which is asigned to every row in a resultset. Do not confuse with rowid which is hash-like and exists phisycally in the table. Since rowids go 1,2,3...n, they provide a way to join two unrelated tables.

```
select
    t1.c1,
    t2.c2
from
    (select rownum rn,c1 from a) t1 left join 
    (select rownum rn,c2 from b) t2 on (t1.rn=t2.rn)
```

**NOTE:**

I assumed A had more rows than B so I made a left join. You can turn things around should B have more rows than A.

Comment: I don't think it will work this way,even if A has more rows than B , after joining in above example in question the value in second column will be null after 4th row .

Answer (score 0):

I would take the modulus of the row numbers, using a 0 base instead of the default 1. This example assumes we know A contains more rows than B. A window function is used to pull the maximum row number with one logical read rather than calling COUNT(*) separately.

```
  WITH a_ AS (SELECT c1, ROWNUM - 1 AS rn, MAX(ROWNUM) OVER(PARTITION BY 1) AS max_rn FROM a),
       b_ AS (SELECT c2, ROWNUM - 1 AS rn, MAX(ROWNUM) OVER(PARTITION BY 1) AS max_rn FROM b)
SELECT a_.c1, b_.c2
  FROM a_
 INNER JOIN b_
    ON b_.rn = MOD(a_.rn, b_.max_rn)
 ORDER BY a_.rn ASC;
```